# Changing layer name with setName produces NoneType error

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to create a python script to automate some algorithms we used to run manually at the office using QGIS 3.16.
Although I am able to produce the desired outputs, the layer names are those by default, which I find confusing, so I want to change them to new ones.

I am trying using the layer.setName method with the following code:

```
Atlas = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(points_to_path['OUTPUT'])
Atlas.setName("Atlas")
```

Even though these lines of code work when using them in the QGIS python console, they do not work from the script, producing the following error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setName'`

Any ideas why this is happening? I have just recently started with Python (or with code in general) so I put the code I am writing in case this error comes from some other part of the code.

```
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
       QgsProcessingParameterNumber,
       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink)

from qgis import processing
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink,
                       QgsProject,
                       QgsFeature,
                       QgsVectorLayer
                       )
from qgis import (processing)
from qgis.core.additions.edit import edit
from qgis.utils import iface

class algTest(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    OUTPUT_1 = 'OUTPUT_1'
    OUTPUT_2 = 'OUTPUT_2'
    OUTPUT_3 = 'OUTPUT_3'

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def name(self):
        return "algTest"

    def displayName(self):
        return "algTest script"

    def createInstance(self):
        return type(self)()

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.INPUT,"Capa de fotos"))

        # We add a feature sink in which to store our processed features (this
        # usually takes the form of a newly created vector layer when the
        # algorithm is run in QGIS).
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                self.OUTPUT_1,
                "Atlas"
            )
        )
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                self.OUTPUT_2,
                "Fotos"
            )
        )
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                self.OUTPUT_3,
                "Táboa de fotos"
            )
        )
        

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        repro = processing.run("native:reprojectlayer", {
                'INPUT': parameters[self.INPUT],
                'TARGET_CRS': 'EPSG:25829',
                'OUTPUT': 'memory:reproxectada'
            },context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True
            )

        calc_x=processing.run('native:fieldcalculator',
                {
                'INPUT':repro['OUTPUT'],
                'FIELD_NAME':'X',
                'FIELD_TYPE':1,
                'FIELD_LENGTH':10.0,
                'FIELD_PRECISION':0.0,
                'FORMULA':'$x',
                'OUTPUT':'memory:calc_x'
                },context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True
                )
        calc_y=processing.run('native:fieldcalculator',
                {
                'INPUT':calc_x['OUTPUT'],
                'FIELD_NAME':'Y',
                'FIELD_TYPE':1,
                'FIELD_LENGTH':10.0,
                'FIELD_PRECISION':0.0,
                'FORMULA':'$y',
                'OUTPUT':'memory:calc_y'
                },context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True
                )
        autoincrement=processing.run('native:addautoincrementalfield',
                {
                'INPUT':calc_y['OUTPUT'],
                'FIELD_NAME': 'Orde',
                'START': 1,
                'SORT_EXPRESSION':'\"Y\"',
                'SORT_ASCENDING':False,
                'OUTPUT':'memory:autoincrement'
                },context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True
                )
        calc_plano=processing.run('native:fieldcalculator',
                {
               'INPUT': autoincrement['OUTPUT'],
               'FIELD_NAME':'Plano',
               'FIELD_TYPE':1,
               'FIELD_LENGTH':10,
               'FIELD_PRECISION':0,
               'FORMULA':'CASE\
                            WHEN "Orde"  <= 8 THEN 1 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >8 AND "Orde" <=16 THEN 2 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >16 AND "Orde" <=24 THEN 3 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >24 AND "Orde" <=32 THEN 4 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >32 AND "Orde" <=40 THEN 5 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >40 AND "Orde" <=48 THEN 6 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >48 AND "Orde" <=56 THEN 7 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >56 AND "Orde" <=64 THEN 8 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >64 AND "Orde" <=72 THEN 9 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >72 AND "Orde" <=80 THEN 10 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >80 AND "Orde" <=88 THEN 11 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >88 AND "Orde" <=96 THEN 12 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >96 AND "Orde" <=104 THEN 13 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >104 AND "Orde" <=112 THEN 14 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >112 AND "Orde" <=120 THEN 15 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >120 AND "Orde" <=128 THEN 16 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >128 AND "Orde" <=136 THEN 17 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >136 AND "Orde" <=144 THEN 18 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >144 AND "Orde" <=152 THEN 19 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >152 AND "Orde" <=160 THEN 20 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >160 AND "Orde" <=168 THEN 21 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >168 AND "Orde" <=176 THEN 22 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >176 AND "Orde" <=184 THEN 23 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >184 AND "Orde" <=192 THEN 24 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >192 AND "Orde" <=200 THEN 25 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >200 AND "Orde" <=208 THEN 26 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >216 AND "Orde" <=224 THEN 27 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >224 AND "Orde" <=232 THEN 28 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >232 AND "Orde" <=240 THEN 29 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >240 AND "Orde" <=248 THEN 30 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >248 AND "Orde" <=256 THEN 31 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >256 AND "Orde" <=264 THEN 32 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >264 AND "Orde" <=272 THEN 33 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >272 AND "Orde" <=280 THEN 34 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >280 AND "Orde" <=288 THEN 35 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >288 AND "Orde" <=296 THEN 36 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >296 AND "Orde" <=304 THEN 37 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >304 AND "Orde" <=312 THEN 38 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >312 AND "Orde" <=320 THEN 39 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >320 AND "Orde" <=328 THEN 40 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >328 AND "Orde" <=336 THEN 41 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >336 AND "Orde" <=344 THEN 42 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >344 AND "Orde" <=352 THEN 43 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >352 AND "Orde" <=360 THEN 44 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >360 AND "Orde" <=368 THEN 45 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >368 AND "Orde" <=376 THEN 46 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >376 AND "Orde" <=384 THEN 47 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >384 AND "Orde" <=392 THEN 48 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >392 AND "Orde" <=400 THEN 49 \
                            WHEN "Orde" >400 AND "Orde" <=408 THEN 50 \
                            END',
               'OUTPUT':'memory:calc_plano'
               },context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True
               )      
        points_to_path=processing.run('qgis:pointstopath',
                {
                'CLOSE_PATH':False,
                'INPUT':calc_plano['OUTPUT'],
                'GROUP_FIELD':'Plano',
                'ORDER_FIELD':'Orde',
                'OUTPUT':parameters[self.OUTPUT_1]  #Saída do modelo para o atlas, OUTPUT_1
                },
                context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True
                )
        calc_data=processing.run('native:fieldcalculator',
                {
                'INPUT':calc_plano['OUTPUT'],
                'FIELD_NAME':'Data',
                'FIELD_TYPE':2,
                'FIELD_LENGTH':100.0,
                'FIELD_PRECISION':0.0,
                'FORMULA':'concat(substr( "Name",7,2),"/", substr( "Name",5,2),"/", substr( "Name",1,4))',
                'OUTPUT':'memory:calc_data'
                },context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True
                )
        calc_hora=processing.run('native:fieldcalculator',
                {
                'INPUT':calc_data['OUTPUT'],
                'FIELD_NAME':'Hora',
                'FIELD_TYPE':2,
                'FIELD_LENGTH':8.0,
                'FIELD_PRECISION':3.0,
                'FORMULA':'concat(substr( "Name",10,2),":", substr( "Name",12,2),":", substr( "Name",14,2))',
                'OUTPUT':'memory:calc_hora'
                },context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True
                )
        calc_directorio=processing.run('native:fieldcalculator',
                {
                'INPUT':calc_hora['OUTPUT'],
                'FIELD_NAME':'Directorio',
                'FIELD_TYPE':2,
                'FIELD_LENGTH':300.0,
                'FIELD_PRECISION':3.0,
                'FORMULA':'"Path"',
                'OUTPUT':parameters[self.OUTPUT_2]  #Saída do modelo para capa que contén as fotos para o deseñador, OUTPUT_2
                },context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True
                )

        refactorizacion=processing.run('native:refactorfields',
                {
                'INPUT':calc_directorio['OUTPUT'],
                'FIELDS_MAPPING':[{'expression': '\"Orde\"', 'length': 10, 'type': 4, 'name': 'Foto', 'precision': 0},
                {'expression': '\"Data\"', 'length': 101, 'type': 10, 'name': 'Fecha', 'precision': 0},
                {'expression': '\"Hora\"', 'length': 254, 'type': 10, 'name': 'Hora', 'precision': 0},
                {'expression': '\"X\"', 'length': 10, 'type': 2, 'name': 'X', 'precision': 0},
                {'expression': '\"Y\"', 'length': 10, 'type': 2, 'name': 'Y', 'precision': 0}],
                'OUTPUT':parameters[self.OUTPUT_3]
                },context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True
                )
        Atlas = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(points_to_path['OUTPUT'])
        Atlas.setName("Atlas")
        return {self.OUTPUT_1: Atlas}
```

I am sure there are way better ways of doing these tasks, but as I said, I am just starting and this is as far as I know how to go.

EDIT: I haven't been able to solve the error, but I did find a workaround by defining sinks with the desired names and then appending the output features and fields.

Comment: You shouldn't access `QgsProject` from `processAlgorithm()`. Perhaps this can help you https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2021-March/063284.html

Comment: Thanks, but using context.project() does not seem to solve my problem...

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but if you `print(points_to_path['OUTPUT'])`, I'm nearly sure you will see a path to a vector layer. The method `QgsProject.instance().mapLayer` expects an id from an existing layer.

So, you should try

```py
Atlas = QgsVectorLayer(points_to_path['OUTPUT'])
Atlas.setName("Atlas")
```

Comment: Using QgsVectorLayer the error disappears, although the name remains the same. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Does `Atlas = QgsVectorLayer(points_to_path['OUTPUT'], "Atlas")` work better?. It does the same as above 2 lines in one line

Comment: It doesn't work either. As it happened before the error disappears but the names remain unchanged.